# concentrate 2 arrays of vectors

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Hi I have 2 arrays of vectors:

```
A=np.array([[5,62,7],[5,62,7],[5,62,7]])
B=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
```

and I would like to concentrate them like that:

```
C=[[[5,62,7], [1,2,3]],
   [[5,62,7], [1,2,3]],
   [[5,62,7], [1,2,3]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newish `stack` makes this easy:

```
In [130]: A=np.array([[5,62,7],[5,62,7],[5,62,7]])
     ...: B=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
     ...: 
In [131]: np.stack((A,B), axis=1)
Out[131]: 
array([[[ 5, 62,  7],
        [ 1,  2,  3]],

       [[ 5, 62,  7],
        [ 1,  2,  3]],

       [[ 5, 62,  7],
        [ 1,  2,  3]]])
```

It adds an extra dimension to each of the arrays, and then concatenates.  With `axis=0` is behave just like `np.array`.

```
np.array((A,B)).transpose(1,0,2)
```

joins them on a new 1st axis, and then moves it over.

Comment: np.stack((A,B), axis=1) this is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`hstack().reshape()` to the rescue:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[5,62,7],[5,62,7],[5,62,7]])
B=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])

c = np.hstack((A,B)).reshape(3,2,3)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
 [[[ 5 62  7]      [ 1  2  3]]

 [[ 5 62  7]      [ 1  2  3]]

 [[ 5 62  7]      [ 1  2  3]]]
```

- [hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)
- [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)